# jquery getting GET variables from javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, get, parameter-passing

I have a link, and when a user clicks it, it pushes a javascript file onto the page. in addition to that, it adds on parameters to the javascript src example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripfile.js?r=some%values&u=more&values">
```

This isn't getting passed through URL on browser. I was wondering how I would get these parameters inside javascriptfile.js?

**javascriptfile.js**:

```
(function(){
     //how to get r value, u value?
}());
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this: http://jsfiddle.net/9Mvxb/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/mKNPT/1/ **And** http://jsfiddle.net/mKNPT/3/

**Please note** if you are not comfortable using `class` see this **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/24UdH/

API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

further in case you wondering about `val.indexOf("?") + 1` why `+1` it is to avid `?`

This should help, `:)`

**code**

```
$("script").each(function(){
   if ($(this).prop('src').split("?")[0].indexOf("javascripfile.js") )
          value = $(this).prop("src");
});

var returnStr = value.substr(value.indexOf("?") +1);

alert(" value after ? is ==> " + returnStr);

var spliMe = returnStr.split('&');

alert("value of R ==> " + spliMe[0]);
```

**OR**

```
    var value = $(".foo").prop("src");

    var returnStr = value.substr(value.indexOf("?") +1);

    alert(" value after ? is ==> " + returnStr);

    var spliMe = returnStr.split('&');

​
```

**tag**

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="foo" src="javascripfile.js?r=some%values&u=more&values">
```

Comment: @undefined Bruver Howz life `:)` Thank-you I shall return this awesomenss lemme see your answer somewhere :)

Comment: This answer seems to work great so far... but it echo's out `r=`, `u=` as well. I'm just trying to get the values not the `r=` and `u=`. Do I have to call these out in the script to remove it? Or is there another faster way? Thanks for the great examples!!

Comment: @andrewliu Glad it helped you! yes you got it right! or I made small demo for you to get rid of `r=` **see here**: http://jsfiddle.net/24UdH/2/ , have a nice one,