# get variable from javascript src

Tags: javascript

I include javascript with params:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.min.js?ver=1.13"></script>
```

How can i get value of variable `ver` from this script?

Comment: i dont think this is possible. maybe put another script tag infront with the version: `<script>var version = '1.13';</script>`

Comment: If it's a global variable in that script, you can just call it, after the script has been included.

Comment: @Chiel92 impossible `$(document).ready(function(){console.log(ver)});` `ReferenceError: ver is not defined`

Comment: And of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11279071/102441)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:
Add an id to script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.min.js?ver=1.13" id="script_id"></script>
```

and then:

```
var src=document.getElementById("script_id").src;
alert(src.split("ver=")[1]);
```

Note that I assumed there is one parameter and this parameter is ver.

Comment: You may solve it even without an id using this: `document.querySelectorAll('script[src^='js/app.min']')`

Comment: Hmm good point :). I think your solution is much better than mine.

Comment: While it may not be quite as elegant, selecting by id would be much more efficient.

Comment: Accessing script tag by using id must be faster than traversing all script tags and comparing src attribute with 'js/app.min'. But if there aren't lots of script tags, then using querySelectorAll shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Id would be the fastest way - no argument there. But maybe it's not possible for the OP to change the DOM. It was just an addition to show another way and not to say that one is better over the other.